# Email Regular Expression - Excluded Specified Set

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have been researching a regular expression for the better part of about six hours today.  For the life of me, I can not figure it out.  I have tried what feels like about a hundred different approaches to no avail.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

The basic rules:

1 - Exclude these characters in the address portion (before the @ symbol): `"()<>@,;:\[]*&^%$#!{}/"`

2 - The address can contain a ".", but not two in a row.

I have an elegant solution to the rule number one, however, rule number two is killing me!  Here is what I have so far.  (I'm only including the portion up to the @ sign to keep it simple).  Also, it is important to note that this regular expression is being used in JavaScript, so no conditional IF is allowed.

```
/^[^()<>@,;:\\[\]*&^%$#!{}//]+$/
```

Comment: regex may not be what you are looking for, since the regex to recognize a valid email is something like this: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @SJuan76: That's for an email without comments. It's also for an obsoleted (twice) RFC.

Comment: @Porges Could you point me to the current version of the regex? I am very curious :-)

Comment: @SJuan76: It depends on your regex engine. The full email address format isn't regular (it can contain arbitrarily nested parentheses), so you have to use non-regular features of the regex engine. I did one for .NET here: http://porg.es/blog/validating-email-addresses-with-dot-net-regex

Comment: @SJuan76, RFC 2822 obsoleted RFC 822.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: And RFC5322 obsoleted RFC2822.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you always choose what characters you want to allow instead of the opposite, you never know what dangerous characters you might miss.

Secondly, this is the regular expression I always use for validating emails and it works perfectly. Hope it helps you out.

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i
```

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that the '+-]' was a range.  Stupid of me.  I spent a chunk of today debugging grammars and my eyes must be getting blurry.

Answer (score 1):

Rule number 2

```
/^(?:\.?[^.])+\.?$/
```

which means any number of sequences of (an optional dot followed by a mandatory non dot) with an optional dot at the end.

Consider four two character sequences

1. `xx` matches as two non dot characters.
2. `.x` matches as an optional dot followed by a non-dot.
3. `x.` matches as a non-dot followed by an optional dot at the end.
4. `..` does not match because there is no non-dot after the first dot.

One thing to remember about email addresses is that dots can appear in tricky places

```
"..@"@.example.com
```

is a valid email address.

The `"..@"` is a perfectly valid quoted local-part production, and `.example.com` is just a way of saying `example.com` but resolved against the root DNS instead of using a host search path.  `example.com` might resolve to `example.com.myintranet.com` if `myintranet.com` is on the host search path but `.example.com` always resolves to the absolute host `example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to your specifications:

```
^(?![\s\S]*\.\.)[^()<>@,;:\\[\]*&^%$#!{}/]@.*$
```

It's just your regex with `(?!.*\.\.)` tacked onto the front. That's a negative lookahead, which doesn't match if there are any two consecutive periods anywhere in the string.

*Properly* matching email addresses is quite a bit harder, however.

Comment: in JavaScript, `/^(?!.*\.\.)[^()<>@,;:\\[\]*&^%$#!{}//]+@.*$/` will match `"\n..@"` because `.` does not match line-breaks.  There is no `s` flag in JavaScript to change the behavior of `.`.

Comment: yeah, it's kinda gross.  You can always replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.

Comment: That's a bit nicer, I'll use that.